# spring kafka versions incompatibility

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, compatibility

I'm trying to integrate kafka in one of services on the project, however it is already integrated in another service, so I naturally tried to use the same kafka version using these two dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:3.1.5.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.2.15.RELEASE'
```

but all I got was this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'kafkaProducerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory]: Factory method 'kafkaProducerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/kafka/core/MicrometerProducerListener
```

After getting that I looked up kafka spring compatibility matrix (https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka/#quick-start) and accordingly updated my project to

```
implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.7.14'
```

the service worked, so I tried to upgrades the same dependenie, but eventually got the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogAccessor
```

its really weird to me because spring versions are the same on both services, right know I'm using different versions kafka dependencies on these services, but maybe someone can bring some clarity to the question why this is happening and why I can't just use the compatibility matrix? (maybe this is just the wrong matrix?)

Also Gradle build file for the first service:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.21'
    id 'com.github.bjornvester.wsdl2java' version '1.2'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.lombok' version '1.5.21'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.3.0'
}

group = 'abc'
version = '1.5.3'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

wsdl2java {
    wsdlDir = '../providers' as File
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.7.RELEASE") {
            bomProperty("kotlin.version", "1.4.30")
        }
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR3"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:5.1.9.RELEASE"
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.9.RELEASE'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.3'

    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter:5.4.0'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-logback:5.4.0'
    implementation 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:4.25.0'
    implementation 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-jdbc-template:4.25.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.+"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.9.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.2.4.RELEASE'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation group: 'com.rabbitmq', name: 'amqp-client', version: '2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:3.+'
    implementation 'org.antlr:ST4:4.0.+'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.60'
    implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-core'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.9.12'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20090211'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.12.23'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.12.23'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:3.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.2.15.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jms'
    implementation "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.0.10"
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
}
```

And the second one:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.bjornvester.wsdl2java' version '1.2'
}

wsdl2java {
    wsdlDir = '../providers' as File
    generatedSourceDir = '../providers/ruru/build/generated/wsdl2java/sources/wsdl2java/java' as File
}

group = 'abc'
version = '1.1.13'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url 'https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons'}
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.1.9.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.3.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wcs.wcslib:wcslib-vaadin-widget-recaptcha:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.9.12'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-server:8.14.3'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:8.14.3'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled:8.14.3'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-compatibility-themes:8.14.3'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:8.14.3'
    implementation 'com.vaadin.addon:jpacontainer:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.+'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5'
    implementation 'dev.samstevens.totp:totp:1.6.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20090211'
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.+'
    implementation("io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter:5.4.0")
    implementation("io.sentry:sentry-logback:5.4.0")
    implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:3.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.7.14'
    
    runtimeOnly 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Spring Framework version (5.1.9.RELEASE) is too old; it's generally best to just specify the Boot version and it will bring in the correct versions of all dependencies, using its dependency management feature.

Also, spring-integration-kafka must be 5.5.x (per that matrix).

Comment: so that means I can just remove versions of all dependencies since I already added plugin 
' id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'' 
in the beginning? sounds risky taking in account age of the project, but I will try this out